# WatchKit : Attributed string 'String ' contains NSFontAttributeName that isn't a UIFont (SanFranciscoDisplay-Light). Removed

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, watchkit

I am getting the following error

> Attributed string 'String ' contains NSFontAttributeName that isn't a
>   UIFont (SanFranciscoDisplay-Light). Removed

Which doesn't make any sense to me because it should be a valid font according to this. http://iosfonts.com. Here is my code.

```
 atrString = NSAttributedString(string: atrString.string, attributes:
            [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(),
                NSFontAttributeName:"SanFranciscoDisplay-Light"])
```

I am trying to access the San Francisco font from my watch kit code. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if that is the correct string name for that font and style?

Comment: I went to the link above and typed the exact same font.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFontAttributeName` is a key that should contain a value of type `UIFont`.

Try `UIFont(name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Light", size: 25)` with the size being whatever font size you want.

`atrString = NSAttributedString(string: atrString.string, attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(), NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Light", size: 25)])`